# I do not understand why array[0] and [1] became null

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NoteIt {
  public static void main(String[]args) {

     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
     int Answer;
     int i=2;

     System.out.print("\nPlease Enter your Name: ");
     String Name = s.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Welcome to Note-It "+Name+", We hope you'll enjoy our application. ");

     String[][] Main = new String[2][2];

     Main[0][0]="Create new Note";
     Main[1][0]="View My Notes";

     while(true) {

         System.out.println("\nPlease select what to do: \n");

         for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
             System.out.println((n + 1) + ") " + Main[n][0]);
         }
        
         System.out.print("\nPlease enter your response: ");
         Answer = s.nextInt();

         if (Answer == 1) {
            i++;
            Main = new String[i][2];
            System.out.print("\nTitle: ");
            Main[i - 1][0] = s.next();
            System.out.print("Body: ");
            Main[i - 1][1] = s.next();
         } else if (Answer == 2) {
            for (int k = 2; k < i; k++) {
                System.out.println(k - 1 + Main[k][0]);
            }
        }
    }

  }
}
```

why did array main become null after one while loop?? When I run the program once everything is perfect, but in the second loop "create new note" and "view your notes", both become null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Main = new String[i][2];
```

Here you created a new Array

If you want to Resize the array you  have 2 options

1. Either use java.util.ArrayList or java.util.Vector instead of native array
2. Or Create a new array and copy old data into new array

Comment: Then what should I do instead??

Comment: If you are creating a new array yoou need to copy old values in it

Comment: I do not want to create a new array but I want to upgrade the dimensions of the array 'Main'. can you please show me how to do that bro. Because I am very new to java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code made some minor adjustments

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[]args) {

     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
     int Answer;
     int i=1;

     System.out.print("\nPlease Enter your Name: ");
     String Name = s.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Welcome to Note-It "+Name+", We hope you'll enjoy our application. ");

     String[][] Main = new String[10][2];
    //String[] Main1 = new String[2];
     Main[0][0]="Create new Note";
     Main[0][1]="View My Notes";
      /**for( int j=0;j<2;j++ )
        Main[j]= new String[2];*/
     while(true) {

         System.out.println("\nPlease select what to do: \n");

         for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++) {
             System.out.println((n + 1) + ") " + Main[0][n]);
         }
        
         System.out.print("\nPlease enter your response: ");
         Answer = s.nextInt();
         s.nextLine();

         if (Answer == 1) {
            i++;
            
            System.out.print("\nTitle: ");
            Main[i - 1][0] = s.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Body: ");
            Main[i - 1][1] = s.nextLine();
         } else if (Answer == 2) {
            for (int k = 1; k <i; k++) {
                System.out.println(1 + Main[k][0]);
            }
        }
    }
    

  }
}
```

There might be some elements not upto your requirement please change them according to your preferences. Also have fixed the skipping of body.

Answer (score -1):

First, check how the 2D array works. You have declared `new String[2][2]`. Then it works `[0][0], [0][1],[1][0],[1][1]`.

Then check with you value assigning points.